# How does Spring Boot application with application.yml behave for when dependency also has an application.yml file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

What happens if, for a spring boot application. The application has an application.yml defined and also one of the dependencies of the application has an application.yml too.

Will spring merge both the properties, Take the final and boot up?
In case spring merges both the properties, How will common properties be handled?

Answer (score 3):

The two will get merged.

- Properties with the same name: the values in your application's application.yaml will override the values from the dependencies application.yaml.
- Properties which are not overwritten (defined in both yaml) will be taken as they are. Everything which you do not include in your application's application.yaml, will default to the value defined in the dependency application.yaml.

Example:

### application.yaml in dependency project:

```
something:
  first: value1
  second: value2
otherthing:
  third: value3
```

### application.yaml in my application:

```
something:
  first: myvalue1 // this will override value1
mysetup:
  fourth: myvalue2
```

the values not specified in myapplication.yaml will be taken from dependency.yaml

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

Comment: What about application.yml which is spring boot application's property, Does the same logic apply to it too?

Comment: I realised, that my example was a bit misleading. Updated, I hope it is clear now.

Comment: If application.yaml in a dependency and application.yaml in an application are both available via the classpath, they will not be merged. The file that appears first on the classpath will win and any subsequent files in the same classpath location will be ignored.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson If that's the case then how to make the spring application work like the example above so that those 2 application.yaml files are merged together instead of replacing each other? This is to provide default values to the dependency while allowing the main app to override some of these values after importing the dependency.

Comment: @ArmWich If you want to provide default values from a library, you should use an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` registered in `spring.factories` that adds a low precedence `PropertySource` containing the defaults. You may also be interested in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24688 which is tracking making some improvements in this area.